# ASP.Net MVC + Autocomplete Search not working

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm a beginner & I'm trying to develop a autocomplete search box with ASP.Net MVC 5. I use Northwind Database and Entity Framework 6.

Here is my index.cshtml code

```
@model IEnumerable<AutoComplete3.Models.Customers>

<link href="~/Content/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#txtSearch").autocomplete({
            source: '@Url.Action("GetCustomers")'
        });
    });
</script>

@using (@Html.BeginForm())
{
    <b>Name : </b>
    @Html.TextBox("searchTerm", null, new { @id = "txtSearch" })
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
}
```

Here is my CustomerController class

```
public class CustomersController : Controller
{
    northwindEntities db = new northwindEntities();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
       return View(db.Customers);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(string SearchTerm)
    {
        List<Customers> customers;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchTerm))
        {
            customers = db.Customers.ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            customers = db.Customers.Where(c => c.CompanyName.StartsWith(SearchTerm)).ToList();
        }
        return View(customers);
    }       

    public JsonResult GetCustomers(string term)
    {
        List<string> customers;
        customers = db.Customers.Where(c => c.CompanyName.StartsWith(term)).Select(y => y.CompanyName).ToList();
        return Json(customers,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

This code is working when i am searching records, by entering keyword & clicking submit button. But the GetCustomer method cannot be called by the jquery script. Inspect Elements shows following error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function
```

The text box should be suggest Company Names to the textbox itself. How to correct this.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you adding jQuery properly? Check the rendered page ViewSource in browser.

Comment: as per the error message you are not loading jQuery or its plugins properly

Comment: I tried to do it by following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=quQgUNteWxY) video.

& this is how i add Jquery to my view

<link href="~/Content/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script> 

is it wrong?

Comment: move your script tag to bottom of the page

Answer (score 0):

Javascript

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#txtSearch").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetCustomers","Home")',
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { searchTerm: request.term },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return { label: item.CompanyName, value: item.CompanyName };
                        }))

                    }
                })
            },
            messages: {
                noResults: "", results: ""
            },
        });
    })
```

View

```
@using (@Html.BeginForm())
{
    <b>Name : </b>
    @Html.TextBox("searchTerm", null, new { @id = "txtSearch" })
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
}
```

Controller

Please update your controller with [HttpPost]

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetCustomers(string searchTerm)
    {
    List<string> customers;
    customers = db.Customers.Where(c => c.CompanyName.StartsWith(term)).Select(y => y.CompanyName).ToList();
    return Json(customers,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
  }
```

Comment: Same output.
I changed that as follows.

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#txtSearch").autocomplete({
            source: '@Url.Action("GetCustomers", "Customers")'
        });
    });
</script

Comment: ok please wait, i will update my answer and give you appropriate solution.

Comment: Thank you @Banwari. I followed this video to develop this app.

[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=quQgUNteWxY]

Comment: Hi...@Chamith Please use my updated answer above it is working fine..may be its have some design issue.

Comment: @Banvari, I tried your code. I put a breakpoint in the controller method (GetCustomer) and run the project. But the Controller method is not called by the view page. What is the problem there?

Comment: Hi..@Chamith please update line data: { searchTerm: request.term }, only, i used searchTerm parameter in action. And i have updated my answer above also.

Comment: Same output @Banvari bro. Controller method is not called. I'm really fed up with this. Are there any different ways to do this? one more thing to do. Can you give me the google cdn links to include those JQuery and css files?

Comment: Dear same code is working fine with me there is no issue, please add the cdn path in correct sequence like below.

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: If you not able to got the right solution, please let me know i will provide you again step by step whole code... don't worry about this..i think you are missing something.